Database linked to react page for updating a webapp
I'm creating a web app for something in my school. Its based on react but it has mostly html characters since I'm a little new to react.
I need a database to be connected to this web app after I've designed its layout since this is more of a news page for the school and needs to be updated consistently by the teachers (who obviously can't constantly update the code).
How can I make each element connect to a database so that if they need to update the important events page, they can't edit the whole page's pictures and text easily on some sort of database that's really user friendly.
I have never used any sort of database with my projects, so I would highly appreciate it if someone could break this down step-by-step since I'm a little overwhelmed with what I'm supposed to do.
Also, if they replace the text or images on the database, would the CSS of the alignment be messed up on the code or is it fixed?
Thanks!

Well, you are asking a pretty big question, so I'll do my best to start you off with the basics:
Most web applications have 3 components:

A database (postgres, sql server, google firebase, supabase, etc)
A web-server (.net webapp, google firebase server functions, nodejs, etc)
A front end UI (vanilla html & javascript, Reactjs, Vue, etc)

Your end user will interact with the UI which will then call server functions to get database data and make changes to the database. Usually, your server will be in charge of authenticating a user as well.
There's certainly a lot more to be said on the matter, but if you already know how to program in react and don't have the time/skills to extensively learn how to deal with servers & databases, it may be worth checking out firebase: https://firebase.google.com/ or something that is similarily lightweight.
